# Getting all controls in a form using JavaScript or Prototype and enable them?

Tags: javascript, controls, prototypejs

How can I get all controls (radio buttons, selects, text fields and so on) and set their state to enabled?

Comment: *[what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)*

Comment: @zzzzBov that is an awesome link do you mind if I use it when I am answering unclear questions as well? I am also wondering what Joao edited on this question did he add the smiley face or the question mark?

Comment: @Goldentp, I didn't write that post, I simply link to it whenever I find myself asking someone what they've tried. Use it as you will.

Comment: @Goldentp, you can review the version history of the question by clicking on the link over the user's name. He added the [tag:prototypejs] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Prototype.js:

```
$$(":input").each(function (el) {
   el.enable();
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LFQWb/)**.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: You're right, it says Prototype, I've edited my answer.

Comment: This gives me "illegal character" error ... where can I place that? I tried placing it inside a js file in a function.

Comment: Solved the above problem, last thing, how can I limit that to a form? The code gives me ALL inputs from my site, not only those inside a certain form.

Comment: `$('myFormId').select('input').invoke('enable');` or `$$('#myFormId input').invoke('enable');`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about older browsers, you can use:

```
(function (slice) {
    "use strict";
    var elems;

    //select the elements
    elems = document.querySelectorAll('button, input, select, textarea');

    //cast to an array
    elems = slice.call(elems); 

    //iterate over the array
    elems.forEach(function (el) {
        //enable each element
        el.disabled = false;
    });
}(Array.prototype.slice));
```

Otherwise, you'll need to use `document.getElementsByTagName` and iterate over every tag:

```
(function (slice) {
    "use strict";
    var elems,
        elem,
        i,
        l;
    function getElemArr(tag) {
        var els;
        //get the elements
        els = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
        //cast to array
        els = slice.call(els);
        return els;
    }
    //select each type
    elems = [].concat(
        getElemArr('button'),
        getElemArr('input'),
        getElemArr('select'),
        getElemArr('textarea')
    );
    //loop over every element
    for (i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        elem = elems[i];
        elem.disabled = false;
    }
}(Array.prototype.slice));
```

Comment: Or `:input`. If the OP uses jQuery at all.

Comment: Where does it say that they're using jQuery?

Comment: @LeeTaylor, you're right, misread the title, thought it said jQuery or Prototype, not JavaScript or Prototype.